# Using progress bar as border of imageview

Tags: android

I want to put a progress bar to imageview. I tried with following code:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/defaultprofile" />
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="64dp"
    android:layout_height="64dp"
    android:indeterminate="false"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:max="100"
    android:progress="65"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/image" />
```

**circular_progress_bar.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="1dp"
        android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#007DD6"
            android:startColor="#007DD6"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

**circle_shape.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
    android:thickness="1dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="#CCC" />

</shape>
```

**Result:**

[image]

How can I fix it? The progress bar should look like border of imageview. I have to remove the padding.

Comment: try putting your ImageView and Progressbar in a RelativeLayout and then, for your ProgressBar, use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`.

Comment: Looks like progress bar automaticly adding padding. Do you see any padding code in xml files?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9ifo8f Imageview and progress bar 64x64 both of them. But progress bar is have padding.

Comment: did you try what i mentioned in my earlier comment?

Comment: Yes, I sent a screenshoot

Comment: isnt that what you want?

Comment: I want to use progress bar as border of imageview. In screenshot it is not looking like border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so your view looks now like that:

[image]

All you need not to do is changing height and weight of both views - the're different

EDIT: Now you're have this:

[image]

According to http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html

delete this line

```
android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
```

---

SOLUTION: I've already changed some files:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:src="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
        android:style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="65"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Circular Progress bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="32dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="1dp"
        android:useLevel="true"><!-- this line fixes the issue for lollipop api 21 -->

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#007DD6"
            android:startColor="#007DD6"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Circular shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="1dp"
    android:innerRadius="32dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="#CCC" />

</shape>
```

And it looks like:

[image]

Hope it help

Comment: Both of them 64x64 dp. I changed them. And it is looking same as screenshot

Comment: i code I see     android:layout_width="75dp and  android:layout_height="75dp"

Comment: As i said, I changed them to 64

Comment: so update the code. I'd not noticed it. Now you need make smaller imageView or bigger progress bar

Comment: I can't do it. http://prntscr.com/9ifs8j You can see i have to remove these spaces. How can I do it? It is adding padding.

Comment: what is happening when you change `android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"` to `android:innerRadiusRatio="9"`..please try it and say what you are getting